# Google chart tooltip doesn't show digits after decimal

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

The tooltip doesn't show digits after decimal (Price) :

[image: Tooltip problem]

The options :

```
options = {
   seriesType: "line",
   series: {1: {type: "line"}},  
   colors:['#337ab7','black']
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this code to solve the problem:

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ 
    pattern: '#%', 
    fractionDigits: 2
});
```

This will return a Decimal value with 2 Decimal Points. Thanks.